# what can I get sum that string tokens converted int in C++?

Tags: c++

I need to sum 100, 200, 300 in a.txt

**a.txt**

```
2323|A|5|0|2|100
2424|B|6|1|3|200
2525|C|7|2|4|300
```

so I opened this file, and read line by line using getline(), and tokenized.

**main.cpp**

```
for (std::string each; std::getline(split, each, split_char); tokens.push_back(each)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++) {
                std::cout << tokens[i] << std::endl;
                tokens.pop_back();
        }
}
```

As expected, that code printed singly of all things.
so I thought using token **index** to sum values. but my code have error.
"vector subscript out of range" or no compile.

**first try**

```
for (std::string each; std::getline(split, each, split_char); tokens.push_back(each)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++) {
                std::cout << tokens[i] << std::endl;
                tokens.pop_back();

                std::cout << tokens[5] << std::endl;
                std::cout << tokens[11] << std::endl;
                std::cout << tokens[17] << std::endl;

                int a = 0;
                int b = 0;
                int c = 0;
                int sum = 0;

                a = stoi(tokens[5]);
                b = stoi(tokens[11]);
                c = stoi(tokens[17]);

                sum = (a + b + c);
                std::cout << sum << std::endl;      
        }
}
```

**second try**

```
for (std::string each; std::getline(split, each, split_char); tokens.push_back(each)) {
    if(tokens.size() > 4) {
        for (int k = 0; k < ((tokens.size() - 5) / 6) + 1; k++) {
                int sum = 0;
                int change = 0;
                int j = 0;
                j = 6 * k + 5;
                change = stoi(tokens[j]);
                sum += change;
                std::cout << sum << std::endl;
                tokens.pop_back();
        }
    }
}
```

what should I do sum value? and I'm wondering that tokens.size()`s meaning except meaning "size" because second for statement always get an error if not exactly correcting i < tokens.size()

Comment: `for (std::string each; std::getline(split, each, split_char); tokens.push_back(each))` doesn't do what you think it does. Instead of writing complex for loops that you don't understand, prefer to break it into simpler parts.

Comment: Actually now I'm confused. Why do you try to access the 17th element when you've only read in a single element?  What were you trying to do?

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c474e9ab2ed0569 ?

Comment: @Mooing Duck I just wanted sum these values. 17th is just simple things counting index number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are *modifying* the `tokens` vector while you are looping through it.  Don't do that.  You are affecting its `size()`, which accounts for why you are able to go out of bounds.

You say that you need to sum only the last token of each line.  But that is not what your code is trying to do.  There is no need for an inner `for` loop at all. Simply split each line into a local `tokens` vector and then use `tokens.back()` to get the last token, eg:

```cpp
std::string line;
int sum = 0;

while (std::getline(inFile, line))
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    std::string token;

    while (std::getline(iss, token, '|')) {
        tokens.push_back(token);
    }

    // use tokens as needed...

    token = tokens.back();
    sum += std::stoi(token);
}

std::cout << sum << std::endl;
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/cp8sPP)

Comment: thanks a lot. if I want sum other values, what should I do?

Comment: For each loop iteration, you have a new `tokens` vector for the current line, just read out and use values from it using `tokens[index]` as needed. No need to pop anything

Comment: I need to ask for your help! if I want partial sum 5, 7 in a.txt, what should I do? I mean, It is possible direct access to one value(like B)?

Comment: @serin I don't understand what you are asking for. Please provide an example.

Comment: 2323|A|5|0|2|100
2424|B|6|1|3|200
2525|C|7|2|4|300

Comment: @serin OK, but what about that example do you want to do exactly? Sum only odd tokens? Sum only every other line? You need to be more specific.

Comment: 2323|A|5|0|2|100
2424|B|6|1|3|200
2525|C|7|2|4|300 I want to some part sum in same column. ex : 5 in 0 column + 7 in 2 column. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: it`s means not limited odd. every other line.

Comment: @serin I already told you 2 days ago how to do that: "*just read out and use values from it using `tokens[index]` as needed*"

Comment: I only using `tokens[index]`  to get total sum in same column,,

Comment: @serin you are not being clear enough. Do you want to sum 2 numbers on each line? Or sum 2 columns separately? What is the EXACT output you are looking for in the above example? BE SPECIFIC

Comment: I`m so sorry. I confused row and column. I want to part sum in other row, same column. ex) sum [5 in 0 row, 2 column] [7 in 2 row, 2 column]

Comment: @serin then what is the actual problem? You would simply use `tokens[2]` on rows 0 and 2. I'm so lost on what you are asking for. All we're doing is wasting comments going around in circles.

Comment: I don't know how to using rows 0 and 2. because I don't know how many lines read. thank you for your time.

Comment: @serin declare a counter variable initialized to 0 and incremented on each loop iteration. Inside the loop, check the counter as needed, ie you can see if the counter is even using `if ((counter % 2) == 0)`

Comment: Thanks for explaining this to me. I understand!

Answer (score 1):

I would like to structure my code slightly differently.

Rather than try and do everything in the main function split your code up so that you read each line and validate it is correct:

```
#include <iostream>                                                                                    
#include <string>                                                                                      
                                                                                                       
// A structure representing the data we want to parse.                                                 
struct DataLine                                                                                        
{                                                                                                      
    int     v1;                                                                                        
    char    c;                                                                                         
    int     v2;                                                                                        
    int     v3;                                                                                        
    int     v4;                                                                                        
    int     v5;                                                                                        
                                                                                                       
    // An input operator that will read one line of data.                                              
    // If the data is valid will update the variable we are reading into.                              
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& str, DataLine& data)                                 
    {                                                                                                  
        DataLine    tmp;                                                                               
        char        s[5];                                                                              
        std::string extra;                                                                             
                                                                                                       
        if (   str >> tmp.v1 >> s[0] && s[0] == '|'                                                    
            && str >> tmp.c  >> s[1] && s[1] == '|'                                                    
            && str >> tmp.v2 >> s[2] && s[2] == '|'                                                    
            && str >> tmp.v3 >> s[3] && s[3] == '|'                                                    
            && str >> tmp.v4 >> s[4] && s[4] == '|'                                                    
            && str >> tmp.v5                                                                           
            && std::getline(str, extra) && extra.empty())                                              
        {                                                                                              
            // all the data was read and the line was valid.                                           
            // update the correct variable.                                                            
            swap(tmp, data);                                                                           
        }                                                                                              
        else {                                                                                         
            // there was an issue.                                                                     
            // set the stream to bad so that reading will stop.                                        
            str.setstate(std::ios::badbit);                                                            
        }                                                                                              
        return str;                                                                                    
    }                                                                                                  
    // Standard swap method.                                                                           
    friend void swap(DataLine& lhs, DataLine& rhs) noexcept                                            
    {                                                                                                  
        using std::swap;                                                                               
        swap(lhs.v1, rhs.v1);                                                                          
        swap(lhs.c , rhs.c );                                                                          
        swap(lhs.v2, rhs.v2);                                                                          
        swap(lhs.v3, rhs.v3);                                                                          
        swap(lhs.v4, rhs.v4);                                                                          
        swap(lhs.v5, rhs.v5);                                                                          
    }                                                                                                  
};
```

Then the loop you use to read the data becomes really trivial to implement.

```
int main()                                                                                             
{                                                                                                   
    DataLine    data;                                                                               
    int         sum = 0;                                                                            
    // Now we can read the data in a simple loop.                                                   
    while(std::cin >> data) {                                                                       
        sum += data.v5;                                                                             
    }                                                                                               
    std::cout << "Sum: " << sum << "\n";                                                            
}
```

Comment: Hm. I like your `operator>>` better than mine